# Update tfs 2018 version

Tags: tfs

I have TFS on premises version 16.122.27102.1

I saw it's TFS 2018 RTW.

1. What does RTW mean?
2. Will update this to TFS 2018 update 3 cost money?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. RTW is "Release to the web", in your case, this is the first TFS 2018 versoin. I recommend upgrade to TFS 2018 update 3.
2. If you already have TFS so you have a license, the upgrade is not cost money (extensions to TFS such as Test Manager, Package Management, and Private Pipelines require an additional purchase).